# Google X509Trust Manager scan for beta apps

Tags: android-security, trustmanager

Is google scanning only the production apps or is it also scanning the beta versions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about beta, but I submitted a production apk using timed publishing (so it wouldn't be released) and it told me there was a problem in that apk after 10+ hours.